# Are international characters supported by Apache Hive?

Tags: hive

Are we allowed to use international characters (meaning Japanese characters etc.) in our Hive tables?

If yes, then what are the setting we have to change to do this?

One example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hive by default uses UTF-8 encoding, so no need to set any settings for handling different charsets.Just use varchar datatype for the column.

Comment: Is there any specific property we have to change in hive-site.xml ? If yes, could you please share the parameter name